# how to add the input values in python after getting the n-1 values?

Tags: python, input, addition

here first we will get the n inputs from python

```
n,x=list(map(int,input().split()))    --- here we got the values of n,x by input function
```

and second we will also get the n-1 inputs from python

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ", n-1)]
```

also here we got the n-1 numbers as input
example n=3
those n-1 =3-1=2 and those n-1 values are suppose 1 2
now how to add them

Comment: `sum(numbers)` ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

since numbers is an array with all the input values, you can simply do `sum(numbers)` to get the sum of this array